# Is there any need to install nvidia graphics drivers if I am running Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, nvidia, graphics, power-management

I have googled this question and arrived at no answer, so here I am.

If I am going to be running Ubuntu Server, (as before I was running 10.04 Desktop) is there any need to install the Nvidia drivers using, say, 'wget'? I ask this because I am unaware if the drivers only impact the GUI or do they allow for power saving features that the computer could benefit from?

---

*Thanks and regards :)*

Comment: You can use jockey-text to install the drivers, but if you don't enter graphical mode you'll see no benefit from them, power-saving or otherwise, so I suggest you not install them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have no need for nvidia drivers on a server, and the server version of the OS (so long as you are not using a graphical mode) will handle power well enough.

For your information as well, you do not install the drivers with wget, but rather with `apt-get install`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the information. No need to install them then.

I wonder have I been installing my drivers from nvidia the hard way for ages now... Always used wget to get the script from the NVIDIA site then run sudo sh "NVIDIA.Whatever.sh"
--------------
For example - `wget http://uk.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/295.20/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.20.run`
then `sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-295.20.run`

Looks like that's something for another time. Thank you both for your help

Comment: @bunnyDrug: all you have to do is run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

Comment: Much easier, will do that in future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason for nvidia-drivers is in my opinion the GPU-Accelerated computation of BOINC-Units like setiathome or einsteinathome etc. 
I have them running for this reason *ONLY*.

Comment: I wonder with my current GPU (GT420) if it would out preform my CPU on such tasks. I will have to do some research. Then again I'm not sure if my demands for this server will include such things.

Still, nice to know all possibilities!