# Is there any need to install amd graphics drivers if I am running Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, graphics, power-management, ati

I run Ubuntu server (12.04, 64-bit). Is there any need to install AMD drivers for my GPU? I do not intend to use any graphical environment, but I am wondering about power consumption.

PS: This question is similar to the nvidia question here: [Is there any need to install nvidia graphics drivers if I am running Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114247/is-there-any-need-to-install-nvidia-graphics-drivers-if-i-am-running-ubuntu-serv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as in the other question, no. In fact, trying to install a proprietary ATI driver will also pull `xserver-xorg-core` and lots of other things which you don't need on a server. Here is the list of dependencies: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/fglrx